# I get stuck in async/await in my pdf render project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pdf

I don't know what happened, nothing error but the await is not pass.

```
<template>
       <input id="file" type="file" accept=".pdf" @change="onpdf"/>
       <canvas id="pdfViewer"></canvas>
</template>
```

I import this in my project to render my pdf file to canvas.

```
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";
import "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.16.105/build/pdf.min.js";
```

Here is my method:

```
onpdf(e: any) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      if (file.type !== "application/pdf") {
        return;
      }
      const canvas = this.$refs.pdfViewer as HTMLCanvasElement;
      
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = async function () {
        const pdfData = new Uint8Array(this.result as any);
        const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
        console.log(loadingTask); // the console show PDFDocumentLoadingTask
        const pdf = await loadingTask.promise; // I stuck in here nothing happen and no error!?
        console.log("PDF loaded"); // The console have nothing.

        const pageNumber = 1;
        const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNumber);
        console.log("Page loaded");
        const scale = 0.5;
        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d")!;
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        const renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport,
        };
        const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        await renderTask.promise;
        console.log("Page rendered");
      };
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
```

Is there anyway to solves this or I have to find another way to render this pdf file.

Comment: were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to run the same code as you (only on the logical part of the await promise) and I had no problem.
Maybe you can try the following solution:

```js
const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's unclear why this is suggested. It's reasonable to assume that the OP got the idea about loadingTask.promise from somewhere. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/module-pdfjsLib.html shows that getDocument returns task object, not a a promise

Comment: When I do that the error caught on pdf.getPage and it said Property 'getPage' does not exist on type 'PDFDocumentLoadingTask'.

Comment: I have edited my answer to try to solve your problem

Comment: It still not working, the promise still on pending and the result is undefine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const pdfBin = `<PDF as buffer>`
 const pdf: any = await (pdfjsLib.getDocument(new Uint8Array(pdfBin))).promise;
 const page = await pdf.getPage(page_no);
 console.log(page)
 const text = await page.getTextContent()
 return text;
```

This Works for me!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly happened but it seems the issue is with the workerSrc.

When I tried to use the latest version it works perfectly,

> [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@4.0.269/build/pdf.worker.mjs"](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@4.0.269/build/pdf.worker.mjs%22)

For your case,

> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.16.105/build/pdf.min.js

You might have a typo here, 'pdf.worker.min.js' instead of 'pdf.min.js'. Hopefully this is not too late...

Answer (score -1):

Try to change const

```html
pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
```

into

```html
pdf = await loadingTask.promise();
```

You are not calling promise method in my opinion

Comment: I do as you say but it cannot find name pdf and I another error goes on promise();  This expression is not callable because it is a 'get' accessor. Did you mean to use it without '()'? <br>Type 'Promise<PDFDocumentProxy>' has no call signatures.